# Hostapd , PI 3 not working , wifi disappeared after 1 to 3 days

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, hostapd

I am having issue with my WIFI hotspot setup the in Raspberry PI 3, 
using hostapd and static Id, and isc-dhcp-server.

After 1 to 3 days, other device can not see the wifi network , and checked the PI3 hostapd is running, static IP , and wlan0 is up, 
the hostapd can not be restart with service or systemctrl.

Not sure where I should start looking. Help needed and appreciated.

hostapd.conf

```
 
interface=wlan0 
driver=nl80211 
ssid=SSID1234 
hw_mode=g 
channel=5 
wmm_enabled=0 
macaddr_acl=0 
auth_algs=1 
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0 
wpa=2 
wpa_passphrase=PASSPHRASE123123123 
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK 
wpa_pairwise=TKIP 
#rsn_pairwise=CCMP
```

DHCPCD.conf

```
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private 
interface wlan0 
  static ip_address=192.168.125.1/24 
  nohook wpa_supplicant 
interface eth1 
  static ip_address=192.168.126.1/24
```

I am not using dnsmasq, but with my own DNS server. 
the issue should not link to DNS server or DHCP server , the WIFI network is not showing up, and the hostapd can not be restart until reboot the box.

uname

```
4.19.46-v7+ #1231 SMP Mon Jun 3 17:42:48 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

DHCPD.conf

```
default-lease-time 60;
max-lease-time 120;

ddns-update-style none;

subnet 192.168.125.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.125.100 192.168.125.230;
        option routers 192.168.125.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.125.1;
        option domain-name "domain.local";

}

subnet 192.168.126.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.126.100 192.168.126.230;
        option routers 192.168.126.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.126.1;
        option domain-name "domain.local";
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant configuration files that you changed to setup your access point (e.g. hostapd.conf, dhcpcd.conf, dnsmasq.conf, etc.). What tutorial or guideline did you follow?

Comment: @oh.dae.su modified the question , can you help on it.

Comment: can anyone help on this ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I'm running into the same error